# Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on all databases?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Is there a way to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS across all databases? It appears that `USE db` must be specified.

I tried this, but it returns nothing when using PowerShell `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

```
IF DB_ID('db') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'BID_BY_CPT_SPECIAL'
    ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION
    ;
END
```

This query is used in a PowerShell script.

```
$q = @"
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp;
SELECT DatabaseName=cast('' as varchar(100))
     , TABLE_NAME
     , COLUMN_NAME
     , DATA_TYPE
     , ORDINAL_POSITION
 Into  #Temp
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 Where 1=0

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
USE ? ;

Insert Into #Temp
SELECT DatabaseName=''?''
     , TABLE_NAME
     , COLUMN_NAME
     , DATA_TYPE
     , ORDINAL_POSITION
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''BID_BY_CPT_SPECIAL''
 ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION
'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL 

Select * From #Temp
"@

foreach ($db in $DatabaseInstances) {
    $r = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $q -ServerInstance $db
```

=== Update

This query is working with `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

```
$q = @"
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp;
SELECT DatabaseName=cast('' as varchar(100))
    ,TABLE_NAME
    ,COLUMN_NAME
    ,DATA_TYPE
    ,ORDINAL_POSITION
    ,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    ,NUMERIC_PRECISION
    ,NUMERIC_SCALE
    ,IS_NULLABLE
Into  #Temp
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where 1=0

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
USE ? ;

Insert Into #Temp
SELECT DatabaseName=''?''
    ,TABLE_NAME
    ,COLUMN_NAME
    ,DATA_TYPE
    ,ORDINAL_POSITION
    ,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    ,NUMERIC_PRECISION
    ,NUMERIC_SCALE
    ,IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''$TableName''
 ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION
'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL 

Select * From #Temp
"@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into `sp_MSforeachdb`

This will collect data into one Temp table.   Personally, I would move your `WHERE` to the final `SELECT`

**Example**

```
SELECT DatabaseName=cast('' as varchar(100))
     , TABLE_NAME
     , COLUMN_NAME
     , DATA_TYPE
     , ORDINAL_POSITION
 Into  #Temp
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 Where 1=0

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
USE ? ;

Insert Into #Temp
SELECT DatabaseName=''?''
     , TABLE_NAME
     , COLUMN_NAME
     , DATA_TYPE
     , ORDINAL_POSITION
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''BID_BY_CPT_SPECIAL''
 ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION
'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL 

Select * From #Temp
```

Comment: Be careful using sp_MSforeachdb. It will sometimes skip databases. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/ I have seen this happen myself and never figured out why.

Comment: @SeanLange I've seen that mentioned before.  I have yet to witness it myself.  However, I am keeping this in my toolbox https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: This works well in SSMS and sqlcmd. But, it returns nothing from `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - It is added to the question. It is all one command.

Comment: @lit Really not a PS guy, but I'll take a harder look into it.

Comment: Here is another great article on this topic from Gianluca Sartori. https://spaghettidba.com/2011/09/09/a-better-sp_msforeachdb/ He references Aaron Bertrand's article but it is the old link.

Comment: I got this to work. I don't know exactly what I did wrong earlier. I will post the working query in the question. Thanks.